# Help understanding negligible function

Tags: functions, logic, proof-writing

I am having some trouble understanding what a negligible function is. More specifically, I have the following statement:

$\forall f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n>0 \implies nf(n) > n$

I am confused about what $\forall f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ means. Once I understand that, I will be able to better interpret the statement.

Edit: I know the statement is false, I just need to understand what the $\forall f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ means so I can disprove it.

Comment: "for all maps $f$ defined on the set of natural numbers and taking values in the positive reals" - the staement is certainly false for $f(n9=\frac1{n+1}$ or even for $f(n)=1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen but what does that mean? 'for all maps $f$'? Could you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: "map" just means "function" in the way Hagen was using it. "For every function $f$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$ and codomain (sometimes called "target") $\mathbb{R}^+$, ..."

Comment: @MarkS. That makes a lot more sense. What does codomain mean?

Comment: If you have not learned about [codomains/targets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) before the source of the exercise,  it may be a good idea to either review the earlier parts of the associated book/notes. You need to fully understand the notation $f:A\to B$ before tackling a problem like this.

Comment: @MarkS. Thank you. I believe I have learned about that before, I've just never seen it written like that. So $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ means a function with an input of natural numbers (1,2,3...) and for those inputs, an output that is a positive real (0.53, 1, 1.5...)?

Comment: @JohnSmith12345 Yes

Answer (score 0):

$f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ simply means that $f$ is function (or map) from the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ to the positive real numbers $\mathbb R^+$. $\mathbb N$ is then called the domain of $f$ and $\mathbb R^+$ is the codomain. So $f$ takes as an input a natural number and produces a positive real number. $\forall f : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ then simply means that the statement following it holds for all such functions.